# Writing to file in real time before closing it

Tags: c++, caffe

I write my output results which are emitted by `Solver()` function (a function in `caffe` third library), in a file with these command:

```
if(std::freopen("redir.txt", "w", stdout)) {
    std::printf("stdout is redirected to a file\n"); // this is written to redir.txt
    solver->Solve();
    std::fclose(stdout);
}
```

but since the `Solve()` function emits outputs continuously, but the `redir.txt` will not be updated until the ‍`std::fclose(stdout);` is executed. So I can't see the results real time.

How can I update my file in real time?

Comment: 'Real time' has a specific meaning in computing, and this doesn't appear to be it. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Commonly `std::flush` maybe works.

Answer (score 5):

Use [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) at regular intervals to flush the written (buffered) data to the file.

Don't `flush` too often though or performance will be impacted.

Comment: Not sure why this wasn't the accepted answer. It points to documentation and has more info than the accepted one.